# React Native Platform OS is not working suddenly

Tags: react-native

I am using `Platform.OS` to check ios and android. It is working fine, But suddenly it returns me 0 instead of 'ios' or 'android'. After some RND I found that when the app is loading the first time, it returns me 'android' but when I switch the screen and check Platform.OS then it returns me 0 value. I am wondered why it is happening.

I am sharing the console result.

when the app is reloading the first time.

```
 LOG  Platform.OS
 LOG  android
```

after that navigate to the other screen and then check Platform OS.

```
LOG  Platform.OS 
LOG  0
```

I am sharing the code snippet to check Platform

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Platform.OS');
        console.log(Platform.OS);
}
```

Comment: Could you post more code since that just does not explain the case. Maybe you're accidentially assigning some falsy value to `Platform.OS`?

Comment: Hi Samuli, Thanks for your reply. After a long debug I found that It was the React native Backhanlder issue.

Comment: I have a similar problem, could you share a bit more details on what the backhandler issue is? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you used Platform.OS "=" instead of "==" someplace within the code.
Example :

*wrong way:*

```
(Platform.OS ='android')?console.log("this the wrong way):console.log('Oops')
```

*right way*

```
(Platform.OS=='android')?console.log("Youpi it works):console.log('in your dream, this gonna happen again')
```

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me.

I noted that in one place I have checked platform condition using a single equal operator by mistake like

```
paddingTop: (Platform.OS = 'android'? 16 : 4)
```

and then whenever I checked the platform, I always got 16.

So make sure if anywhere you have check condition, like  `Platform.OS = 'android'` replace it with `Platform.OS == 'android'`

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajesh Nasit exposed, I had a similar problem, when I wrote

```
console.log("Platform.OS:" + Platform.OS)
```

I allways was getting in the console "Platform.OS: 100%"
And the followed error (in Expo CLient App) => 'Unhandled promised error :Invalid platform was passed "100%" '.

Then after reversed my code and checking all the changes I've made, I found the line what was the responsible for thar error.

I had in my StyleSheet the following line

```
width: Platform.OS === 'android' ? "100%" : "100%",
```

I asume React-Native somehow set the value "100%" to the Platform.OS.

At final, I resolved that error as follow:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
imagebackground: {
          ...Platform.select({
            ios: {
              width: "100%",
            },
            android: {
              width: "100%",
            },
            default: { 
              width: "100%",
            }
          }),
          marginLeft: 0,
        },
```

Well I hope someone find this answer usefull.